# Remove other language space in html

Tags: java, html, html-parsing, jericho-html-parser

I want to trim the space between the tag name and the attribute using StringUtils.strip(). Because I have some space which cannot be removed by the 
following Jericho methods:

- CharacterReference.decodeCollapseWhiteSpace(htmlFragment))
- TextExtractor
  -Tag[] allTags = source.fullSequentialParse();

the first method removes the normal space but not the other language space.
This is the error I am getting. for example

```
html = "<a　　　href=\"test.html\"><font></font></a>";

StartTag a at (r1,c1,p0) rejected because the name contains an invalid character at position (r1,c3,p2)
Encountered possible StartTag at (r1,c1,p0) whose content does not match a registered StartTagType
```

there is also a generateHTML method in jericho but we have to provide all the attribute values etc

```
public static java.lang.String generateHTML(java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.String> attributesMap)
```

In full sequential parse it does not recognise the other language space.

How can I remove other language space ONLY between the tag name and attribute? ( other language space in between the attribute value is OK) that is why I cannot do `string.replaceALL()`

Comment: It is not a space at all (it just shows as whitespace). So to replace it with Java you will have to replace this character. I would execute that replacement before handing it over to Jericho: Replace your character with spaces, let Jericho clean up any unwanted spaces in the second step.

Comment: I think it is being considered as an invalid character System.out.println("Char Ref:" + source.getParseText().charAt(4)); this is the output Char Ref:¡

Comment: For jericho it is an invalid character, for Java it should not be (unless you are running a localized version of Java). So Java should be able to replace that character. Any idea where the character originates?

Comment: Yes I can replace it in java using StringUtils.strip() , my problem is I need to remove this space ONLY between the tag name and the attribute for the tag to get recognised.(It is a japanese space)

Comment: You could try jsoup instead of Jericho to see if it accepts your space. Else you are pretty much left with replace all (I would not strip them: Replace them with normal spaces, then use Jericho to clean up) or write your own code to recognize html tags and replace unwanted characters.

Comment: Yes I have looked at Jsoup too, thanks for your comments

Comment: How about `html.replaceAll("(?<=<\\w{1,100})[\\s\\u3000]+", " ")`?

Comment: @saka1029 - pl update as an answer, i will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use String.replaceAll().

```
    String html = "<a　　　href=\"test.html\">　　　<font></font></a>";
    System.out.println(html.replaceAll("(?<=<\\w{1,100})[\\s\\u3000]+", " "));
    // -> <a href="test.html">　　　<font></font></a>
```

This code replaces all spaces including `\u3000` (ideographic space) by one space.  The spaces must be preceded by `<ELEMENT_NAME`. But the preceding is not replaced. (See "zero-width positive lookbehind" in [Class Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)) The length of `ELEMENT_NAME` is limited between 1 to 100 in this code.